# Issue with JQuery Each function

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function to hide email ids on the webpage to avoid spambots.
I am trying to replace all the span tags with class 'mailme' to valid email ids with the help of this function. The code was working for 1 span tag but since its changed to multiple spans with the help of each method, its not working.

Html

```
<span class="mailme">myemail at mydomain dot com</span>
```

jQuery

```
$('span.mailme').each(function(){
var spt = "#" + $(this).attr("id");
var at = / at /;
var dot = / dot /g;
var addr = $(spt).text().replace(at,"@").replace(dot,".");
$(spt).after('<a href="mailto:'+addr+'" title="Send an email">'+ addr +'</a>')
.hover(function(){window.status="Send a letter!";}, function(){window.status="";});
$(spt).remove();
});
```

Comment: Those quotation marks look suspicious `:)`

Comment: You are trying to get an ID from an element which it hasn't one.

Comment: @Šime, what?  You don't code in MS Word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/g7Szt/2/

```
$('span.mailme').each(function () {
    var addr = $(this).text().replace(/ at /, "@").replace(/ dot /g, "."),
        s = '<a href="mailto:' + addr + '" title="Send an email">' + addr + '</a>',
        link = $(s);

    link.hover(function () {
        window.status = "Send a letter!";
    }, function () {
        window.status = "";
    });

    $(this).replaceWith(link);
});
```

---

```
<head>
    ...
    <script>
        $(function() {
            // place all jQuery code here
        });
    </script>
    ...
</head>
```

Comment: have corrected the quotes, thanks for pointing that out. But its still not working.

Comment: This is really strange. Since I am new to jQuery, I think I am doing something wrong with the placement of the code. I tried the code and it is working in jsFiddle but not in my HTML. Currently I have placed the code between script tags under head section. No DOM function or onload is being used. Can you tell me what I am missing out?

Comment: @Piyush If the code is in the HEAD element, you have to wrap the code aournd the ready handler. I'll update my answer to explain how to do it.

Comment: @Piyush Note that since the code won't execute until the whole HTML document is parsed, it is irrelevant if the SCRIPT is in the HEAD or BODY. For instance, I put my SCRIPT elements at the very bottom of the page.